# get one random record per combination of two columns (one table)

Tags: sql, oracle, select, random

I have this table

rss_user. You see account name, application name and application type.

with
    RSS_USER_NAME   RSS_NAME    RSS_TYPE

example data

```
tom@gmail.com   webapp4     webapps
tom@gmail.com   webapp6     webapps
tom@gmail.com   mswin3      windows
tom@gmail.com   mswin2      windows
sakur@gmail.com mswin2      windows
sakur@gmail.com webapp6     webapps
```

I wish to get one random account from the combination of rss_name and rss_type. Every combination of rss_name and rss_type should have one random account.

current code. Completly useless :-(

```
SELECT *
  FROM (  SELECT    'SYNC rss_user WITH rss_user_name = "'
             || RSS_USER_NAME
             || '" , rss_name = "'
             || RSS_NAME
             || '" , rss_type = "'
             || RSS_TYPE
             || '";'
        FROM rss_user
    ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE)
 WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

result:

```
SYNC rss_user WITH rss_user_name = "tom@gmail.com" , rss_name = "webapp4" , rss_type = "webapps";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT    'SYNC rss_user WITH rss_user_name = "'
             || RSS_USER_NAME
             || '" , rss_name = "'
             || RSS_NAME
             || '" , rss_type = "'
             || RSS_TYPE
             || '";',
                 seqnum = row_number() over (partition by rss_name, rss_type order by dbms_random.value)
         FROM rss_user
        ) t
 WHERE seqnum = 1
```

That is, use row_number() and dbms_random.value with each other to select a random row.

Comment: thank you very much. Only very small correction from my side.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/sql-server-set-based-random-numbers) is a great discussion on how to generate random numbers row-by-row. Once you understand how to do that, you can just do this (pseudo-code):

```
select rss_name, rss_type, max(rand) from
(select rss_name, rss_type, <random number> as rand from rss_user) a
group by rss_name, rss_type
```

Comment: I think the questioner knows about creating random values, since the code sample includes DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE.  Your answer doesn't answer anything.

Comment: Additionally the "group by rss_name, rss_type" doesn't work, because I need rss_user_name.